# TypeError: my_task() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, django

This is a headscratcher...

I have the following view:

```
def progress_view(request):
    result = hello.tasks.my_task.delay(8, request.POST.get('account_name'))
    return render(request, 'display_progress.html', {'task_id': result.task_id})
```

I also have the following in tasks.py

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def my_task(self, seconds, account_name):
    progress_recorder = ProgressRecorder(self)
    result = 0

    pprint(seconds)
    pprint(account_name)
    for i in range(seconds):
        timeline = api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name=account_name,
                               include_rts=True,
                               trim_user=True,
                               exclude_replies=True,
                               count=2)
        time.sleep(1)
        result += i
        progress_recorder.set_progress(i + 1, seconds)
return result
```

The call:

```
 result = hello.tasks.my_task.delay(8, request.POST.get('account_name'))
```

gives me:

```
 TypeError: my_task() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

The full traceback is as follows:

```
 [2020-02-19 15:28:58,951: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task      
 hello.tasks.my_task[5b4f0731-0c48-4bd3-ac5d-8c585a0758c8] raised unexpected:     
 TypeError('my_task() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given',)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery.  
 /app/trace.py", line 382, in trace_task
 R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery. 
 /app/trace.py", line 641, in __protected_call__
 return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
 TypeError: my_task() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
 [2020-02-19 15:29:30,479: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-6] Task    
 hello.tasks.my_task[a17c78e5-4835-4a31-a000-d0a0955c91e0] raised unexpected:    
 TypeError('my_task() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given',)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery.  
 /app/trace.py", line 382, in trace_task
 R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery.   /app/trace.py", line 641, in __protected_call__
 return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
 TypeError: my_task() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: `my_task` is not an instance method, `self` will not be passed automatically, as I see

Comment: @mrEvgenX how might i pass self?

Comment: It depends on what you expect, to be not confused I'd rename the first argument to something more meaningful. What does need `ProgressRecorder`-class to instantiate? So exactly that you should pass as a first argument.

Comment: @mrEvgenX I dont understand.. :)

Comment: @mrEvgenX i need all the arguments i pass.

Comment: I wanna say this. You have defined `my_task` with three arguments, but want to call it with only two, why? Where did you expect to get `self`? `self` makes sense only in instance methods of any class.

Comment: @mrEvgenX self is implicitly passed as well as the two arguments. How do you pass self explicitly?

Comment: My fault, it seemed familiar, but not. I didn't know about bound tasks in celery.